# Duplicate variable names in MODEL class, error when Obfuscation is done in ANDROID STUDIO

Tags: android, gson, obfuscation

I am learning to Obfuscate my Android Code by making: minifyEnabled = true in my Manifest file.

But GSON has some issues with the Obfuscated code. 
I have tried:

1. Obfusucation should not rename my Model classes & Model class variables.
2. Added @SerializedName on every variable of Model class.

But the error says, I have duplicate variable named as a, in my Model class.
But i don't have any duplicate variable in my Object classes.

> build.gradle

```
release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
debug {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      }
```

Below is my proguard file:

> proguard-rules.pro

```
-ignorewarnings
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
-keep class com.crashlytics.** { *; }

-dontwarn com.crashlytics.**

# Gson specific classes
-dontwarn sun.misc.**

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.* { *; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.masterdata.* { *; }

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.** { <fields>; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.masterdata.** { <fields>; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.register.** { <fields>; }

-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.** { *; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.masterdata.** { *; }
-keep class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.register.RegistrationInputData

-keepclassmembers class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.masterdata.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.register.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.model.register.RegistrationInputData

-keepclassmembers enum * { *; }
```

Error is as below:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hgs.ruralhealth_new, PID: 6577
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class d.h$b declares multiple JSON fields named a
        at com.a.a.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
        at com.a.a.b.a.i.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.a.a.f.a(Gson.java:423)
        at com.a.a.b.a.m.a(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.a.a.b.a.i$1.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
        at com.a.a.b.a.i$a.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
        at com.a.a.b.a.m.a(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.a.a.b.a.i$1.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
        at com.a.a.b.a.i$a.a(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
        at com.a.a.f.a(Gson.java:669)
        at com.a.a.f.a(Gson.java:648)
        at com.a.a.f.a(Gson.java:603)
        at com.a.a.f.a(Gson.java:583)
        at com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.activity.LoginActivity$2.a(LoginActivity.java:457)
        at d.g$a$1$1.run(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

When I copy this error in Proguard, below in the output:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.hgs.ruralhealth_new, PID: 6577
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class d.h$b declares multiple JSON fields named a
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java.util.Map getBoundFields(com.google.gson.Gson,com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken,java.lang.Class)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:170)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.com.google.gson.TypeAdapter create(com.google.gson.Gson,com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:100)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.com.google.gson.TypeAdapter getAdapter(com.google.gson.reflect.TypeToken)(Gson.java:423)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:125)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.void write(com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter,java.lang.Object)(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:243)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.void toJson(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Type,com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter)(Gson.java:669)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.void toJson(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Type,java.lang.Appendable)(Gson.java:648)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.java.lang.String toJson(java.lang.Object,java.lang.reflect.Type)(Gson.java:603)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.java.lang.String toJson(java.lang.Object)(Gson.java:583)
        at com.hgs.ruralhealth_new.activity.LoginActivity$11.void onResponse(retrofit2.Call,retrofit2.Response)(LoginActivity.java:457)
        at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory$ExecutorCallbackCall$1$1.void run()(ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.java:68)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

**Now what code is at LoginActivity.java:457**

```
public void onResponse(Call<PhysiotherapistResponse> call, Response<PhysiotherapistResponse> response) {
            Log.i("Physio Backup==>", new Gson().toJson(response));//This is line 457
```

**BELOW ARE MY MODEL CLASSES:**

> PhysiotherapistResponse.java

```
    public class PhysiotherapistResponse implements Parcelable {

        @SerializedName("status")
        private String status;

        @SerializedName("message")
        private String message;

        @SerializedName("syncFromId")
        private String syncFromId;

        @SerializedName("syncToId")
        private String syncToId;

        @SerializedName("data")
        private List<PhysiotherapistInputData> data;
//////////................GETTERS SETTERS GOES BELOW...........
```

> PhysiotherapistInputData.java

```
    public class PhysiotherapistInputData implements Parcelable {

        @SerializedName("createdDate")
        private String createdDate;

        @SerializedName("swpNo")
        private String swpNo;

        @SerializedName("patientName")
        private String patientName;

        @SerializedName("age")
        private String age;

        @SerializedName("gender")
        private String gender;

        @SerializedName("namePhysio")
        private String namePhysio;

        @SerializedName("painScore")
        private String painScore;

        @SerializedName("exercieAdvice")
        private String exercieAdvice;

        @SerializedName("remark")
        private String remark;

        @SerializedName("isOld")
        private String isOld;

        @SerializedName("doctorId")
        private int doctorId;
//////////................GETTERS SETTERS GOES BELOW...........
```

Comment: Did you add following code in your proguard-rules.pro file?
-optimizationpasses 5                                                      
-dontusemixedcaseclassnames                                                
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclasses                                           
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers
-dontpreverify                                                             
-verbose                                                                   
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!field/*,!class/merging/*

Comment: @Aolphn: Not yet, will check and let you know...

Comment: @Aolphn: I have updated my proguard-rules.pro file. But alas ! it is not working. I am still getting the same error.

Comment: @Aolphn: Could you please have a look at the proguard file and point out my mistake.

Comment: You missed gson's proguard rules ,I posted my anwser,try it.

Comment: The same issue, @Pawan did u able to find the solution?

Comment: @AnantShah: No I gave up this.

Answer (score 0):

add follow proguard rules into your proguard file ,it comes from [here](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/examples/android-proguard-example/proguard.cfg)

```
   -keepattributes Signature

    # For using GSON @Expose annotation
    -keepattributes *Annotation*

    # Gson specific classes
    -dontwarn sun.misc.**
    #-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

    # Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
    -keep class com.google.gson.examples.android.model.** { *; }

    # Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
    # JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
    -keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
    -keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
    -keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer
```